# Eclipse/IntelliJ Userlib (Gloop) loading leads to red screen, BlueJ not

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, bluej, lib

In school we started with Java programming using the Library Gloop (Its completly in german). We use in school BlueJ as Ide but in school it is whithout embedding any librarys possible to use IntelliJ. (Windows)

As I now wanted to do some stuff for this at home (I am using Macos Mojave) I tried to just embed the gloop Library into IntelliJ, but the shown Window just shows red.
I tried this in eclipse by embedding it as userlib too, but same result.
Finally I tried this in BlueJ and it works without any Problems.

Some example code is aviable [here](https://www.brd.nrw.de/lerntreffs/informatik/pages/material/sek2/einfuehrungen/GLOOP1/GLOOPDownloads/Beispielprojekte-GLOOP-3_7.zip).
The Library(Gloop) makes use of gluegen-rt and jogl to use OpenGL.

Because of the working example in BlueJ I expect this to show the example (I tried multiple).
So I expect this to be an issue with importing the Librarys into classpath?

Comment: There are probably some DLLs for OpenGL that run either on a 32 bit or on 64 bit Java. Please show your error (message).

Comment: I checked and both are using 64bit (BlueJ and Eclipse) 
There is no error Message it is justed that the Frame does not show the expected output but just red.